# Update value on df based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a script that loads an excel file using pandas and then iterating through it to update values based on two columns.

The df looks like this:

| id | name | type | paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 1 |  |
| 2 | Mary | 1 | N |
| 3 | John |  |  |
| 4 | George | 1 | N |

If type in row 3 is empty and paid in row 2 is N (or not empty) then I want to update the paid in row 3 to N.
eg. Paid column in John should be N.

The code I have is this, but it doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"data/excel_file.XLS")

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iat[i, 3] == "" and df.iat[i-1, 4] != "":
        df.iat[i, 11] = "N"


file_name = "New.xlsx"

df.to_excel(file_name)
print("Data exported successfully!")
```

I've tried .empty but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You would typically not use a loop in pandas but:

```
# is the type null?
m1 = df['type'].isnull()
# is the previous paid "N"?
m2 = df['paid'].shift().eq('N')

# if both conditions are True, change paid to "N"
df.loc[m1&m2, 'paid'] = 'N'
```

Same thing referencing the columns by position (third column is `2`, fourth is `3`):

```
m1 = df.iloc[:, 2].isnull()
m2 = df.iloc[:, 3].shift().eq('N')

df.iloc[m1&m2, 3] = 'N'
```

Output:

```
   id    name  type  paid
0   1    Mike   1.0  None
1   2    Mary   1.0     N
2   3    John   NaN     N
3   4  George   1.0     N
```

Intermediates:

```
   id    name  type  paid     m1     m2  m1&m2
0   1    Mike   1.0  None  False  False  False
1   2    Mary   1.0     N  False  False  False
2   3    John   NaN  None   True   True   True
3   4  George   1.0     N  False  False  False
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that type is str. Also, when I try this I get error 'function' object has no attribute 'eq'.

Comment: Then replace `isnull()` by `eq('')`

Comment: Regarding your error this shouldn't happen with my code, maybe you mistyped it to `df['paid'].shift.eq('N')`? Double check that you're using it exactly as I wrote it (`df['paid'].shift().eq('N')`)

Comment: This fixed the error but I've checked the generated file and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Provide a [mre], "*it doesn't work*" is meaningless without supporting data